# How to set variables from (.gitlab-ci.yml) in application.properties in non Spring application?

Tags: java, gitlab

I set up a project variable in GitLab - `NONPROD_TEST_VARIABLE`

My gitlab-ci file:

```
variables:
  JAVA_IMAGE_NAME: maven:3.8.4-amazoncorretto-17
  TEST_VARIABLE: ${NONPROD_TEST_VARIABLE}

acceptanceTest:
  image: $JAVA_IMAGE_NAME
  script:
    - ./gradlew test
  tags:
    - nonprod-docker-runner
  when: always
```

I have checked and during job run this NONPROD_TEST_VARIABLE successfully sets in `TEST_VARIABLE`.

I also have `application.properties` file in my resources:

```
##Set Test variable
TEST_VARIABLE=${TEST_VARIABLE}
```

And PropertiesLoader to read variables from `application.properties` during runtime:

```
public final class PropertiesLoader {

  private PropertiesLoader() {}

  public static String getTestProperty() throws IOException {
    return loadProperties().getProperty("TEST_VARIABLE");
  }

  private static Properties loadProperties() throws IOException {
    Properties configuration = new Properties();
    InputStream inputStream =
        PropertiesLoader.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("application.properties");
    configuration.load(inputStream);
    inputStream.close();
    return configuration;
  }
}
```

But during the run of the job in GitLab I'm getting `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException` for this PropertiesLoader.class which means that this variable from gitlab-ci isn't setting successfully in `application.properties`.

It's not a Spring application, I don't have any different environments and I'm using gradle.

```
test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

And there's actually a single test class that is running some tests, I just want my variable from gitlab during the test run

Could someone please tell me what I'm doing wrong? Maybe there's a better way to store and pass these variables or maybe I forgot something?

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to solve my problem. It seems that reading a variable from `application.properties` like I did before is the wrong way for non-spring applications.

I removed

```
##Set Test variable
TEST_VARIABLE=${TEST_VARIABLE}
```

from `application.properties` because it's unnecessary. Variable is set in gitlab-ci.yml directly as I did it before

```
variables:
  JAVA_IMAGE_NAME: maven:3.8.4-amazoncorretto-17
  TEST_VARIABLE: ${NONPROD_TEST_VARIABLE}
```

I'm getting its value from `PropertiesLoader` like this:

```
public static String getTestProperty() {
    return System.getenv("TEST_VARIABLE");
  }
```